# Find div by inner text and adding class

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find a specific `div` by its inner text to adding subsequently a class. How can i do it?

Example input

```
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div>Third</div>
```

Desired output

```
<div>First</div>
<div class="check">Second</div>
<div>Third</div>
```

Comment: Do you use jquery?

Comment: Not really, but if it's required I can implement it

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => { if (div.innerText == "Second") div.classList.add("check"); });`

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).find(x => x.innerText === 'Second').classList.add('check')`

Comment: Ok, thank you @ChrisG you solved my problem. I am sorry for the simple question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have been helpful

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Second');
    if (y>-1) {
        x[i].setAttribute("class", "check");
    }
}
```